# Permission trouble Octopus Tentacle

Tags: octopus-deploy

I'm having some trouble getting an Octopus Tentacle to deploy a package.

It keep telling me that the Tentacle may not have enough permissions to access the application. The tentacle service is running under the Local System account.

[image]

All the files I expect there to be are present and unpacked from which I would assume everything is working as it should.

[image]

The tentacle is working fine. The log files don't show any errors and no information that could give me a hint why this is happening.

I must have configured something wrong or have forgotten something but I can't figure it out

The executing users have full control on the folder. Actually I set it to everybody full control to be sure it's not a permission issue.

Comment: Assigning a different user account does not solve the problem.

Comment: It's probably a silly suggestion, but are you sure the screenshot of Windows Explorer was from the same machine that the deployment was occurring on? *I have to ask because you haven't mentioned checking this in the question*.

Comment: And while I'm pointing out the obvious, the error message says it doesn't have permission, and you haven't stated that you have checked the file permissions for the user doing the deployment.